# file upload HTML PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm new to html and PHP and JS. I learned how html + CSS+ PHP works but I'm kind of struggling to understand JavaScript.
In short code version, most of u knows the rest of the code :)

using (index.html):

```
<form action = "upload.php" method= "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
```

and (upload.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

it works fine..................

but when I try using(script.js) (following a video tutorial I dont get the same result):

```
   function uploadFile(name)
   {
    
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST","upload.php")
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", ({loaded,total})=>{
       let fileLoaded = Math.floor((loaded/total) *100);
       let fileTotal = Math.floor(total/1000); // getting file size in KB
       console.log(fileLoaded,fileTotal);
      });
      let formData  = new FormData(form);
      xhr.send(formData);
   }
```

and removing the (`if statement line -and leaving the code which was inside it-` in my php which checks if the submit button is checked)

and changing my (index.html) to :

```
<form action = "#">
```

I can see the progress in console but the file is no longer being uploaded to my folder using the same code.

I think I know what I'm doing (changing only the lines I want) to my needs, as a c# WinFroms programmer. So I cant tell whats wrong and because I'm new to html and php and javascript I dont know what to try :(

Comment: You have omitted important pieces of code which makes answering this tricky. How is this function called? Does the `submit` button have type attribute `submit` or `button`? Is there an `onclick` handler assigned to the button or is there an event handler bound to the file input field? Please add the complete HTML form

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius using html with a button and php that checks if the button is clicked i can upload files, but when i use javascript with file.OnChange that calls a function (uploadFile) which upload the file automatically when a file is choosen and removing the if statement (for the button click event) the file isn't uploaded although i can see the progress in the console

Comment: Your Javascript doesn't submit a field named 'submit' therefore $_POST['submit'] is not set and whatever is in the curly brackets won't get executed.

Comment: @AltimusPrime OP said they removed the _"if statement line"_. I presume that means the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: In your JS code, where is `form` defined? Please [edit] your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make sure you show how `uploadFile()` is triggered

Answer (score -1):

I have this example

```js
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // console.log("pk");
    $("#fileToUpload").change(function() {

document.getElementById('myBar').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('myProgress').style.display='block';

if(document.getElementById('loader1').style.display=='none') { 
    document.getElementById('loader1').style.display='block'; 
} 
// return false;
        
        var formData = new FormData($('#upload_form')[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../functions/up/claims_mitigation_files.php?type=<?php echo $_GET["type"]; ?>",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        // var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        var percentComplete = Math.round(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total);
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                        $('#status').html('<b> Uploading -> ' + percentComplete.toString() + '% </b>');
                        
                        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
                        var width = 1;
                        var id = setInterval(frame);
                        function frame() {
                            if (width >= 100) {
                            clearInterval(id);
                            } else {
                            width++; 
                            elem.style.width = percentComplete.toString() + '%'; 
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#status").html('UPLOADED!!');
                location.reload();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: i think this is a bit complicated to me at my current -500 level in javascript :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 2x nested `( document ).ready()`? Strange mix of jQuery and plain JS?  This is not good code, and not a good recommendation for anyone learning.

Comment: I'm not inclined to vote down this answer, because I don't like to vote down answers, but this is not relevant to the question. The original poster has a form with a submit button, which is included in the POST data, but the JavaScript has no such field. Your solution gives a JQuery example of a front end that doesn't resolve that.

Comment: _"claims_mitigation_files.php"_... where did this come from? This answer doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question. This post is also not tagged with [tag:jquery]